# SSLException: Could not find any key store entries to support the enabled cipher suites

Tags: java, android, ssl

I want to implement a small android application, that works as SSL Server.
After lot of problems with the right format of the keystore, I solved this and run into the next one.

My keystore file is properly loaded by the KeyStore class. But when I try to open the server socket (socket.accept()) the following error is raised:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Could not find any key store entries to support the enabled cipher suites.

I generated my keystore with this command:

> keytool -genkey -keystore test.keystore -keyalg RSA -keypass ssltest -storepass ssltest -storetype BKS -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath bcprov.jar

with the Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy for Java SE6 applied to my jre6.

I got a list of supported ciphers suites by calling

```
socket.getSupportedCipherSuites()
```

that prints a [long list](http://nopaste.info/23b45dc075.html) with very different combinations. But I don't know how to get a supported key.
I also tried the android debug keystore after converting it to BKS format using portecle but get still the same error.

Can anyone help and tell how I can generate a key that is compatible with one of the cipher suites?

Version Information:

targetSDK: 15
tested on emulator running 4.0.3 and real device running 2.3.3 
BounceCastle 1.46
portecle 1.7

Code of my test application:

```
public class SSLTestActivity extends Activity implements Runnable {
SSLServerSocket mServerSocket;
ToggleButton tglBtn;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    this.tglBtn = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

    tglBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                new Thread(SSLTestActivity.this).run();
            } else {
                try {
                    if (mServerSocket != null)
                        mServerSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("SSLTestActivity", e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keyStore.load(getAssets().open("test.keystore"), "ssltest".toCharArray());

        ServerSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
        mServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket) socketFactory.createServerSocket(8080);
        while (!mServerSocket.isClosed()) {
            Socket client = mServerSocket.accept();
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            output.println("So long, and thanks for all the fish!");
            client.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SSLTestActivity", e.toString());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Keystore does not support enabled cipher suites*

It's not really up to the keystore to support or not a cipher suite. It's the `SSLSocket` (or engine) that supports them. What it's looking for is a key, in the keystore, of a type suitable for one of its supported cipher suites. Typically, enabled cipher suites are RSA or DSS based, so it will look for an RSA or DSA key respectively.

In the following code:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keyStore.load(getAssets().open("test.keystore"), "ssltest".toCharArray());

ServerSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
mServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket) socketFactory.createServerSocket(8080);
```

You're not doing anything with your `keyStore`. You might as well not load it at all in this case (and you should always close the input stream you read from, by the way).

Here, you're still using the default `SSLServerSocketFactory`, which you haven't specifically configured (and for which there is no default keystore): this is why you get "*Could not find any key store entries to support the enabled cipher suites*": it can't find a suitable key store entry, because it can't even find the key store.

You would need to configure an `SSLContext`, initialise it with a `KeyManager` built from your keystore and then get a server socket factory from it.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Using SSLContext fixed the problem :)

Comment: Thanks a ton for this. I was getting all sorts of errors because I was trying to get an SSLServerSocketFactory out of an SSLContext which was only initialized with TrustManagers, not KeyManagers. Your explanation and code really helped, cheers :)

Comment: I've got the same problem, but it remains even if I use `SSLContext`. There seems to be a problem with my self-signed certificate, but I don't know how to solve it. I posted my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49416868/tls-secured-tcp-server-and-client-with-self-signed-certificate). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might come too late for you but for others along the ways.

> keytool -genkey -keystore test.keystore -keyalg RSA -keypass ssltest -storepass ssltest -storetype BKS -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath bcprov.jar

created the keypair successfully and in theory should worked.

What I am not sure of is the content of the keypair. If you had left everything as the default (ie enter enter all the way), the CN will be of value "Unknown". I ran through a few iteration of test and confirm it. CN=Unknown will generate  keypair successfully (Can confirm that with Keytool -list) but will fail during the the SSL negotiation. Somehow it will fail to find the key required to establish the secure connection.  (The below will fail with the above mentioned exception)

> ```
> File: C:\Users\James\Downloads\test.keystore
>     Type: BKS-V1
>     Provider: BC
>     Keys
>         None
>     Key Pairs
>         mykey
>             Last Modified: 07/Aug/2015 16:07:13 ICT
>             Private Key
>                 Locked - unlock to get properties
>             Certificates
>                 Unknown
>                     Version: 3
>                     Subject: CN=Unknown,OU=Unknown,O=Unknown,L=Unknown,ST=Unknown,C=Unknown
>                     Issuer: CN=Unknown,OU=Unknown,O=Unknown,L=Unknown,ST=Unknown,C=Unknown
>                     Serial Number: 5BA77D0F
>                     Valid From: 07/Aug/2015 16:07:13 ICT
>                     Valid Until: 05/Nov/2015 16:07:13 ICT
>                     Public Key
>                         Algorithm: RSA
>                         Key Size: 2048 bits
>                         Format: X.509
>                         Encoded: 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
>                         Public Exponent: 0x10001
>                         Modulus: 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
>                     Signature Algorithm: SHA256WITHRSA
>                     MD5 Fingerprint: 47:F8:40:B9:05:71:CF:30:36:8D:B4:28:7D:FE:B7:6F
>                     SHA-1 Fingerprint: 11:6F:A3:28:7F:87:97:E7:14:CE:63:A1:9D:09:85:CF:E4:7E:FE:E8
>     Trusted Certificates
>         None
> ```

BTW: For Windows Dev, you might want to consider Key Explorer as compare to Keytool. It has more functionality than Keytool.